# Show more than 4 folder in the Quick Access list on Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there a way to show more than 4 folders in the Windows 10-Explorer quick access list at the left?

I can, of course, manually pin folders. But that's not what I meant. I mean the dynamically built list of recent folders.

Is there a way to set it to show (say) 6 or 8 folders instead of just 4?

Comment: One option is to edit the registry. Or you can right click File Explorer in taskbar to get around 10 recent folders.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Thanks! If I right click File Explorer in the bottom Task Bar I still only see 4 folders. Confused. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Do you know what Registry key needs to be edited?